# I want to return a function and have it evaluated in the calling module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  I wrapped my function in an anonymous function with the belief that it wouldn't get evaluated until it was called elsewhere.  But I'm getting an error about "dropchart" not being defined, so it's getting evaluated within this module.

```
define(function() {
  var stage = {
    before: {
      createCanvas: function() {
        return function() {
          before(function(done) {
            this.canvas = new dropchart.Canvas({
              canvas: argsFor.canvas(),
              data: argsFor.data()
            });
            done();
          });
        };
      }
    }
  };
  return stage;
});
```

This is how it is called from the other module:

```
define(['jquery', 'dropchart', 'argsFor', 'stage'], 
  function($, dropchart, argsFor, stage) {

  var should = chai.should();
  var xAxisSpec = {

    run: function() {

      describe('xAxis', function() {

        stage.before.createCanvas();

        ...
```

Comment: are you sure something from this module isn't called? and if this is a module, where is `dropchart` defined?

Comment: I'll update to show the other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stage` module has the `argsFor` and  `dropchart` dependencies, **not** the calling module.

The calling module cannot somehow make those available for `stage` module, unless you pass them as arguments in `stage.before.createCanvas` or you put them to global scope which defeats the whole point of require.js